# some thing wrong when install sharp

Tags: node.js, linux, centos7, sharp, nodebb

when I try to install nodebb and init it with command "nodebb setup", and 
then install third-part pack automatically, it always runs into an error, the error msg as below。

**yes it alway `sharp`, I hate that.**

I don't know why not permission, I'am root role.
I tried to mkdir by myself but the npm remove it and then told me, "permission denied", excuse me?????

I try to install `sharp` with `npm install sharp --ignore-scripts` and install the dependence by myself. by this way can I run the nodebb server, but when I try to upload an image from the browser, and sharp it, the nodebb got an error as below the last

#### this is some erro msg with install:

```sh
[root@bbs NodeBB]# npm install sharp
> sharp@0.23.0 install /home/bbs/NodeBB/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
info sharp Using cached /root/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
ERR! sharp EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/bbs/NodeBB/node_modules/sharp/vendor'
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/page/install for required dependencies
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/bbs/NodeBB/node_modules/sharp/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/share/node-v12.9.1-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/share/node-v12.9.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/bbs/NodeBB/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.23.0 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.23.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-11T06_23_30_748Z-debug.log
```

#### this is some error msg when upload image:

```sh
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp.node'
Require stack:
- /home/bbs/NodeBB/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
- /home/bbs/NodeBB/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
- /home/bbs/NodeBB/src/file.js
- /home/bbs/NodeBB/require-main.js
- /home/bbs/NodeBB/app.js

- Remove the "node_modules/sharp" directory, run "npm install" and look for errors
- Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/
- Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues
```

Comment: my os is centos7, and node `12.9.1`, nodebb `1.12.2` mongodb `4.0`(maybe has no related with this)

Comment: Try to install from ordinary user, not root. I.e. in your case try to install from user bbs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I resolved it, but I don't know how

I used this command:`sudo chown -R $(whoami) node_modules/`

Keep in mind that you shouldn't use root for anything more than system administration.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error after upgrading Node from v10 to v12. My projects still used the `node_modules` that have been installed when I had v10. So I guess they get installed differently with another Node version. The following helped me:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

Now every installed node module used the latest latest Node version during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you live in the same country as me, so the biggest reason is the GFW.
I once encountered the same problem as you.
You can try to modify the npm mirror source for this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with **sharp** install, trying to install NodeBB 1.12.1. The problem seems to be with an outdated sharp version. 
I resolved it correcting the required sharp version in package.json.
Here is the solution:

- clone the repository

```
    git clone https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB.git nodebb
```

- checkout to the required branch

```
    git checkout v1.12.1
```

- go to ~/nodebb/install and in package.json change required sharp version to 0.22.1

```
    {"dependencies: {
    ...
           "sharp": "0.24.0",
    ...
    }
```

- now, start the setup process

```
    ./nodebb setup
```

Everything should work fine now.